# I can't find the command equivalent to keys in Stack Exchange Redis

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I just switched to Stack Exchange Redis, and I could'nt find the command keys equivalent.
Is it omitted or in some other place rather than getdatabase()?

Answer (score 8):

See https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan

This command (for reasons discussed in the link) is a server command, not a database command, and is available via `GetServer(...).Keys(...)`.

Comment: Outdated link: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan#so-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: @MaksimVi. thanks; the transition to github pages was worth it, but not without consequence

Answer (score 5):

Also, as per

http://redis.io/commands/keys

Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using sets.

Check if this helps :

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/b823aed448ff3eff2c22b1cdae80446629fcf8bd/Docs/KeysScan.md